# how to store the select options value and text in an JSON object or Array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, select, hash

I have a select list (sample below). I want to store this select list (text and value) in a JSON object or Array object. So that i can later go thru it using .each function. I want to then show/hide the records in the select option list based on user input. all code is ready and working except that I am not able to figure how to store a select option list with all its text and value pairs into an either Array or JSON object and subsequently able to walk thru it based on text.

thank you.

```
 <select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/nnYWm/):

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple"> 
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3">Third</option> 
    <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var options = {};

$('#mySelect option').each(function(){
    options[$(this).text()] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(options);

//or the other way round

var options2 = {};

$('#mySelect option').each(function(){
    options2[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
});

console.log(options2);
```

Console Log Output:

```
Object
First: "1"
Fourth: "4"
Second: "2"
Third: "3"
__proto__: Object
fiddle.jshell.net:36

Object
1: "First"
2: "Second"
3: "Third"
4: "Fourth"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: thx. i am using your option2 piece. I am using it to create a JSON object in memory from the select options list. I am then trying to use this JSON data to grep a given string in the 'text' portion. I am not able to figure yet how to grep in a JSON object. ----previously I was saving only the 'text' in the array and was using .each to iterate thru array and storing indexes of items which do not contain the given string, and thus hiding them. ----  now i do not know how to grep the JSON object for any given string.... can you help? thx.

Comment: Also, i tried <pre><code>...<code><pre> and back ticks, but my code is still not printing like everyone elses. help!! :(

Comment: Take a look at [underscorejs.filter](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter). You can use it to filter an object like this: `_.filter({a:1,b:2}, function(value, key, elements){ if(value === 1) return elements[key]});` => returns: `[1]`. Underscore has a small footprint and offers many ways to filter/map/reduce arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very similar to @[topek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973527/how-to-store-the-select-options-value-and-text-in-an-json-object-or-array/7973616#7973616)'s but I'm using object to store array elements so it may be useful. You can inspect working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/Aty7Q/).

**HTML:**

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var options = [];
$('#mySelect option').each(function() {
    options.push({ "id" : this.value, "text" : this.textContent });
});
```